# Xubuntu 14.04 system sound not working?

Tags: xubuntu, system

There are no system sounds as far as I can tell and there is no option for setting this in settings. Speakers are working fine as I'm able to play Youtube Videos.

Its a fresh 14.04 LTS install.

All help is appreciated.

Edit: I'm sorry for not putting things in better words. Yes, Youtube sounds and Songs, movies etc are working fine. Its just sound indication/system sounds which were played as  a feedback from system during events. 
E.x:Login sound.

2nd Edit: I was able to get Log-in sound working by following [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1869787&page=2).
However, nothing else has worked to get other sounds working which are mentioned in there.

3rd Edit:

Problem;

```
XXXXX:~$ xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Net/EnableEventSounds
false
XXXXX:~$ xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Net/EnableInputFeedbackSounds
false
```

Found solution, looks like this was set to false so I had to change it to True using following commands, not sure why it was on false though.

```
xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Net/EnableEventSounds -s True
xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Net/EnableInputFeedbackSounds -s True
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you hear sound when you play youtube vids or not? if not, try this, type `alsamixer` in the terminal and navigate using the arrows and keep pressing `m` to unmute all

Comment: You edit 3 solves the problem, but it requires lowercase boolean value.

Answer (score 1):

This drove me crazy.  Make sure Pulse Audio Volume Control is installed. 
To install open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`

This took me forever to find but worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Search for `Pulse Audio Volume Control` in XFCE menu, Go to `playback` section, you will find the system sounds section. It must have been muted

[image]

Comment: It is not muted. Actually its set for 100%. :/

Answer (score 0):

Search for PulseAudio in XFCE menu. Go to **Output Devices** section. You will find the mute audio button. It might have been muted.

[image]